# Lissajous in canvas

Tags: html, canvas

i need lissajous curves in Canvas. In curves should swim dot.I use this in school, but i can t this do, because i am new in this. 
Curves should look like https://www.intmath.com/trigonometric-graphs/svg/svgphp-lissajous-figures-7-s2.svg
Thanks in advance.

```js
function draw_lissajous(omega, sigma, cycles) {
  var canvas = $('#scena').get(0);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var c_h = 500;
  var c_w = 500;
  var step = 0.01;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var i=0; i<(cycles * Math.PI*2) + step; i+=step) {
    var x = Math.sin(omega*i + sigma);
    var y = Math.sin(i);
    var scale=200;
    ctx.lineTo(c_w/2 + (x*scale), c_h/2 + (y*scale));
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
function update() {
  var omega = parseFloat($('input#omega').val());
  var sigma = parseFloat($('input#sigma').val());
  var cycles = parseFloat($('input#cycles').val());
  if (isNaN(omega)) omega = 0;
  if (isNaN(sigma)) sigma = 0;
  if (isNaN(cycles)) cycles = 10;
  draw_lissajous(omega, sigma, cycles);
}
$('input').keyup(function() {
  update();
});
update();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lissajous Curves</title>
</head>


<body>
<canvas id='scena' width=500 height=500>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what result are you getting if not your curves? Can you give more detail? Where are the inputs for `omega`, `sigma`, and `cycles`?

Comment: Omega,sigma and cycles should be a var, curves should be a level and look as this https://www.intmath.com/trigonometric-graphs/svg/svgphp-lissajous-figures-7-s2.svg. Line X and Y novisible. In curves should swim small ball

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't what I was asking. I was asking about what you *are* seeing, not what you *should* be seeing. Also, how do you intend to set the values of omega, sigma, and cycles? I know they are variables, but I don't see any inputs in your HTML to set the values.